# Поиск значения слова

Tags: значение-слов, однокоренные-слова

Не могу никак отыскать подходящее слово ( да и не знаю, какие можно было бы взять ). Но знаю его значение. Какое слово подойдет вот по такому правилу(?):

Если:

```
информация -> информативность
```

то

```
совет      -> ?
```

Comment: У слова *совет* не одно значение, а, по крайней мере, три. Какое Вы имеете в виду?

А как это понимать? *Поиск значения слова. <=> Но знаю его значение.*
Помогите читателям.

Comment: @Hermit, я знаю, что оно должно обозначать - "советуемость", но слова такого в русском языке нет, но, наверняка, есть с таким же значением( или хотя бы близким к нему ).

Comment: Вам нужно подобрать пароним к слову "совет"? Вряд ли отыщется. Напишите предысторию вопроса,что именно надо сделать, может, не пароним надо искать? От слова совет какие существительные?-совещание, советник,советчик,советолог, прилагательное советский - свойственный Советам

Comment: Есть ещё "советскость" - свойственность советскому образу жизни

Comment: Совет:
1) рекомендация, подсказка, помощь словом
2) совещание
3) орган власти

информация — информативность (характеристика текста, канала связи),
1) совет — дивергенция (шутка :)), 
2) совет — совещательность (потенциал собрания по нахождению решения).
-------------------------------------- 
Это — для разогрева, а в целом я — пас.

Comment: Даже не знаю, как грамотнее было бы описать то, что нужно. В общем, человек, который дает советы, причем это не должно относиться к мужскому или женскому роду, т.е нечто среднее между "Советником" и "Советчицей".

Comment: @Hermit, ну вот, мне понравилось синонимичное выражение "помощь словом". А есть ли у этого выражения синоним-существительное( в одно слово, разумеется )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "советуемость" образовано от глагола *советовать*.
Совет (обсуждение, совещание) - обсуждаемость, совещательность (темы, вопроса);

совет (пожелание, наставление) - пожелательность, наставительность, "советность".
Ссылки на **советность** :
http://libc.omgpu.ru/cgi-bin/irbis64r/cgiirbis_64.exe?LNG=&Z21ID=&I21DBN=STAT&P21DBN=STAT&S21STN=1&S21REF=3&S21FMT=fullwebr&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21LOG=1&S21P03=K=&S21STR=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

http://www.slova.ru/article/34166.html

Цитата из Даля :

> **советность, советливость**, свойство или состояние по прилаг., доброхотство и дружелюбие, ласка, мир и тишина, вообще лады в семье.

Comment: Вот она золотая середина - "Советливость"! Спасибо Далю и вам, что разыскали ценную цитату. Интересно, а эта форма слова не является ведь устаревшей?

Comment: Слово *советливость* легко возродить. Начните его активно употреблять, и народ подхватит.

Comment: В этом значении устарело, но появилось новое значение-"свойство человека, дающего советы по поводу и без повода"

Comment: Спасибо. Благодарю вас)

Answer (score 1):

А в каком значении у вас "совет"?
Если орган власти, то "соборность"  (немного церковное слово, но оно есть).
Если совещание, то "коллегиальность", "совещательность".  
Если предложение, мнение, высказанное кому-то, то, пожалуй, тоже пойдет "совещательность".

PS На ответы Груманта, я не обращаю внимания в принципе, так что извините, если у него что-то такое было.

Comment: Спасибо вам за "Совещательность". Тоже хороший синоним.

Comment: Довольно зобавно, что вы не нашли первое же приходящее на ум.
Совещание - слово, исторически однокоренное "совету". Собственно совещание и есть "совет" в исходном значении этого слова.

Comment: @behemothus, ну, я не сказал, что я его не находил. Просто поблагодарил вас за слово)